# Difference between turtle.onclick and turtle.onscreenckick()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

What's the difference between those two turtle events? And can you give the turtle.onscreenclick parameters included with the x and y coordinates? for example turtle.onscreenclick(x,y, some_variable)
I want it such that on clicking a certain range of coordinates on the turtle graphics window, another function is started. See below:

```
def click_event(x, y):
    if turtle.xcor() >= 0 and turtle.xcor() <= 100 and turtle.ycor() >= 0 and turtle.ycor() <= 100:
        print('Click position at ', x,y)
        calcSum(num1, num2)
    else:
        print('You are out of range')

def calcSum(number1, number2):
    my_sum = number1 + number2
    return my_sum

def main():
    # Call the functions in the main function
```

How would you call this function in the main function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `onclick()` methods, one for setting a function to execute when you click on a turtle, and one for setting a function to execute when you click anywhere on the screen.  The event handler function for clicking anywhere on the screen is also fired if you click on a turtle, if both are enabled, turtle first, then screen.

The dual *functional* and *object-oriented* nature of the turtle module can get confusing on this issue.  The default turtle's `onclick()` method is the global `onclick()` function.  The singular screen instance's `onclick()` method is the global `onscreenclick()` function.  This is one reason why I recommend the import:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
```

rather than `import turtle` or `from turtle import *`.  It brings in the object-oriented API for turtle and blocks out the functional API, to avoid confusion.  Roughly, your code snippet would be:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def click_event(x, y):
    if 0 <= x <= 100 and 0 <= y <= 100:
        print('Clicked position at:', (x, y))
        calcSum(x, y)
    else:
        print('You are out of range')

def calcSum(number1, number2):
    my_sum = number1 + number2

    turtle.clear()
    turtle.write(my_sum)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(click_event)
screen.mainloop()
```

If you click just to the left and above the origin, you'll get a sum written to the screen.  Note that event handlers you define don't `return` anything as their caller is not in a position to do anything with the return value.  Your event handling must *do* something, not *return* anything.